# Google Ads Datatransfer transfering way less products than show in the dashboard

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I have a bigquery google ads datatransfer, I'm only interested in the products table.

Each day I only get 22 000 products,  google ads dashboard would show me way more (*10).

I know products without performances (no impressions / no clicks) are not transfered. But still, I'm lacking too much lines.

If anybody knows what could cause this ? Thanks a lot in advance

I tried to compare the products with performances on the google ads dashboard with those in my bigquery datatransfers, the two don't add up